# google-api-client-java eclipse build path and google app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am trying to follow the instructions here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

I have decided to download the google-api-java-client library and see if I can instantiate the code on the bottom half of the page referenced above. I have imported libraries in eclipse in my app engine project so that eclipse doesn't complain about anything BUT when I try this:

```
    GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(mJFactory, tokenString);
```

eclipse complains with red underlining on 'GoogleIdToken.parse()' and this text

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.JsonWebSignature. Fix the build path then try building this project

and

> The type com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.JsonWebSignature cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have gone to this site and have followed the instructions as closely as I can, but the error remains.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_Library_with_Dependencies

can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

The jars with version 1.12.0-beta were not working for me, (as described above) but 1.13.2-beta was released and seems to work fine.

BTW, I was willing to try anything, including different versions of eclipse and wiping my eclipse workspace metadata. I even tried older versions of the google api library, which actually worked. I was going to go with 1.9, but I found out the last one (1.13) had some useful options that I wanted to take advantage of. 1.13.2-beta got rid of the eclipse errors for me.